# C# how to count sum of spesific part of textfile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text-files

I have a text file like this:

```
IPen ID Datetime                                    Status
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:17:23        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:17:26        NG
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:17:30        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:17:47        NG
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:17:50        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:17:53        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:17:57        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:18:00        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:18:03        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:18:06        NG
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:18:10        OK
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:18:13        NG
48      Tuesday, September 27, 2016 14:18:17        NG
```

I want to count how many `status` is `OK` and how many `status` is `NG`.
Is it possible to combine `lines.count` and `lines.contains` together or any another way?
Thanks for your help and responses.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: i am confuse what must i start from, any suggestion for me ?

Comment: You should convert your text file into csv file and then you can achieve this .

Comment: @MarioDS : thanks bro i absolutely learn it.

Comment: @bharatpatidar : but my company just want to only text file not CSV file

Comment: if you already have code where you can write `line.Contains(string)`, then make it `if(line.EndsWith("OK")) ++okcount; else ++nogoodcount;` for a quick and cheap solution

Comment: Start by looking at `System.IO.File.ReadLines()` , that gives you 1 line at a time. Then think about breaking it up or how reliable you can get the last 2 chars

Comment: @dlatikay but you don't know this text is for Status only or not

Comment: I infer that from the sample with 99,9% probability :-) as does the answer below. but you are right it needs to be specified of course

Comment: @yosafat you must have to convert you file into table then only you will be able to count specific content for status

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you do it. The only thing you should care about how your file format is really stable. If you are sure that OK and NG are always upper case and are at the end of the line, you can do it this ways. Otherwise, you should find a set of stable conditions.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = @"c:\temp\file.txt";
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        var oks = lines.Count(s => s.EndsWith("OK"));
        var ngs = lines.Count(s => s.EndsWith("NG"));
        Console.WriteLine("OKs: {0}, NGs {1}",oks,ngs);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks my bro. yes its totally what i need. thanks for solution and sharing